# Does there exist a Vector that can't be written as a Tuple of Scalars?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

**The most abstract/general definition of a vector**

The most general definition of a vector is as an element of a vector space. Given a vector $u$, we can always say that there exists a vector space $V$ that $v$ is an element of.

*i.e.* $$\exists \  V : u \in V \ , \forall u$$

**Vectors defined as tuples of scalars**

A scalar defined most generally is an element of a field $\mathbb{F}$ (e.g $\mathbb{R}$ and  $\mathbb{C}$), with a field just being a set satisfying the axioms of addition and multiplication. For example any real number (being an obvious element the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$) is a scalar.

We know that we can write vectors as $n$-tuples of scalars.

A vector $w$ as an element of the vector space $\mathbb{R^n}$, can be written in terms of scalars as elements of the field of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$.

$$w = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1}  \\     
    x_{2}   \\   
    ... \\
    x_{n}       
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$

---

**Question :**

Given a vector $u$ as an element of a vector space $\mathbb{F^n}$, can we always find a $n$-tuple of scalars as elements of some field $\mathbb{F}$ to represent $u$ by? Asked more formally :

> ***Given $u \ \in \mathbb{F^n}$, can we say $\exists \ T : u \cong T$***
>
> where $T$ is some arbitrary $n$-tuple : $T = (x_1, x_2, ... x_n)$ 
>   and where $x_i \in \mathbb{F}$?

Put more simply : *Does there exist a vector that can't be written as a tuple of its scalars?*

---

This answer to this question may be brutally obvious (maybe so obvious that it's like asking can we write a number in terms of a number), in which case I apologize, or it may be a valid question.

Perhaps the reason why I ask this might be more clear, is by attempting to define vectors in metric or topological spaces, i.e. how would this definition of a vector, change in higher mathematical spaces. That's what I'm attempting to think about. I realize that I've only *really* asked about defining vectors as tuples of scalars in vector spaces specifically, but I've just added this last bit here, so you can see where I'm coming from.

Comment: What does $\mathbb{F}^n$ mean to you ?

Comment: This is true. You have to specify a basis for your vector space first. After that you can write your vector in terms of the basis and the coefficients in that expression are the entries of the vector you call $T$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Any abstract Vector Space

Comment: Notice that this means that $u$ can be represented as a vector in multiple ways. The representation depends on the choice of basis.

Comment: A vector space can have infinite dimensions. It can still have a basis but it may require a linear combination of infinitely many basis vectors to produce an arbitrary vector $u$ in that vector space. Is the (infinitely long) list of coefficients of those basis vectors an "$n$-tuple" according to your meaning of that term? (I won't complain if the answer is "yes", but if it's "no" then there may be other consequences.)

Comment: @DavidK Yes. I would say that based on what I know of tuples, that would constitute a tuple. I'm curious however, what are the consequences if I had said "No", and is my answer of Yes even correct?

Comment: I think "yes" is fine. I just wanted to check. If you really wanted the tuple to have only a finite number of members then I think it would have worked only for finite-dimensional vector spaces (which is still a lot of vector spaces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is, by definition, $F^n$ *is* the set of $n$-uple $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ with $x_i\in F$. That's the very definition of the symbol $F^n$. And indeed $F^n$ is a vector space over $F$.

Now if you start with an "abstract" vector space $V$, then what you want to prove is that $V$ is isomorphic to $F^n$ for some $n$ (which is the dimension of $V$).

The theorem is then that every finite-dimensional vector space has a *basis* : a family (here finite) $(e_1,\dots,e_n)$ of vectors such that every vector $v$ can be written $v= \sum_i x_ie_i$ in a unique way. This defines a bijection $V\to F^n$ which is easily seen to be a vector space isomorphism.

Note that this is not canonical : choosing another basis gives another isomorphism $V\to F^n$.

Also note that for some spaces (those of infinite dimension) you will have to consider an infinite number of coordinates (but this is probably beyond your concerns).

Comment: This is slightly misleading: while every vector space has a basis, that basis may not be finite! E.g. consider the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$ of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. There is no way to view an element of $V$ as a finite tuple of reals.

Comment: That's why I wrote "here finite". I edited to insist on that point.

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb{F}$. Let $\{v_1,\cdots,v_n\}$ be a basis for $V$. Let $u \in V$. Since the $v$'s form a basis, there are scalars $a_1,\cdots,a_n \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $u = a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n$. Let $T$ be the tuples $(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ then $T$ is a representation of $u$ as a tuple.

Comment: Note that this proof requires you to accept the existence of bases. In the cases of a finite dimensional vectors space, it is not difficult to prove that bases exist. For infinite dimensional vector spaces, you can prove bases exist using Zorn's Lemma.